# Chabad Method of folding Tallis under instead of over?

Tags: tzitzis, tallit-gadol

So i've been struggling at times during Shacharis trying to prevent my tallis gadol from unraveling and sliding off my shoulder, it oddly mostly seems to happen on the right side and less frequently on the left side. I fold it upwards onto the shoulder, but i think Chabad folds it from under, which seems more practical and lesser chances of it sliding off. However i've tried to tuck it under but it always gets jammed or stuck midway and doesnt go flat on my shoulder or the tziszis at the back tend to be on my shoulder rather than behind shoulder. What can i do?

Comment: Try folding it up until it fits on your shoulder, and then roll the edges under a few times.

Comment: Ashaynem dank N.T i will try that tomorrow morning.

Comment: Ashaynem dank N.T tried it this morning. It stayed on whole time beginning to end for Shacharis. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I learned it from my bar mitzvah teacher. I'll make it an official answer since it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Ask someone that folds their tallis this way to show you how is a good option. If there is a chabad house near you I'm sure the shliach would be happy to help. Alternatively while it seems to not be very common I have occasionally seen clips used to help the tallis from slipping off. Is it possible your tallis is just not big enough? If there is only a s.all amount of material on your shoulders the tallis is more likely to fall off. Lastly, there are tallesim that are designed with a non slip weave.

Best of success

Comment: The tallis gadol i use is 36x72 i think, and when i fold it up onto the shoulder the sides hang past my shoulders a bit over the bicep/tricep area. i even tried folding it under after the intial top upwards fold and during the elokai netzor section after amidah it started to slowly unravel and then the top upwards fold also slowly started coming off. its not a issue to readjust it it just messes with the kavanah during tefillos is all so i like many other yidden prefer it not lol

Answer (score 1):

Try folding it up until it fits on your shoulder, and then roll the edges under a few times.